# Does an analysis/optimization tool like SqlYog exist for SQL Server 2005 (and later)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, disk-space

I'm curious about effective space allocation of my tables, so:

- does something like [SqlYog](http://www.webyog.com) exist for SQL Server 2005 (and later)?

Of course I know SSMS, but I was looking for something more precise like column space allocation, and so on... I'd like to find a tool for analysis and optimization of structures and queries.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft provided, for free, [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) (SSMS) starting with SQL Server 2005. Is it not exactly like SqlYog but there are similarities. With regards to table space I would direct you to the [Standard Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/buckwoody/) that were added to SSMS after SQL 2005 SP2. They provided a more eye friendly look at allocation of space, index usage, performance information, etc.

Comment: Of course I know SSMS, but I was looking for something more precise like column space allocation, and so on... I'll give you my point because I could easily be misunderstood (as you did).

Comment: Why not just edit your question and be more specific on what you were looking for, instead of just taking the answer I provided? It will allow the question to hold more worth on the site and it won't hurt my feelings at all...

Comment: thank you :) I didn't know if it was right (according to the site rules).

Answer (score 1):

I really like Idera's SQL Diagnostic Manager, although it's pretty pricey.  SQL Diagnostic Manager has taught me that I can typically use the system DMVs to get the answer I'm looking for.  If I persist enough, there is usually a way of finding out exactly what you want.